# MySQL Combining Tables Specific Order

Tags: mysql, merge, sql-order-by, records

This seems to be a convoluted problem, but I'll try my best to articulate the idea and illustrate a scenario. Essentially I have two tables that need to be combined and returned as the result set for a single query. One table needs to be merged into the other in a specific order.

Say table one is called **Articles** and table two is called **Features**. Both tables have an *ID* field with unique numbers. **Articles** has a date field which will be used to initially sort its records in descending order. The **Features** table has a *Delta* field which be used initially to sort its records. Some of the records in the **Features** table are placeholders and are not meant to be included in the final set. Their only purpose is to affect the sort order. Each record has a unique value in the *Delta* field, from 1 - X which will be used to sort these records. Another field called *Skip* has a value of *1* if it should be eliminated when merging the two tables together. Again, the only purpose to the skipped records is to take up space during the initial sort on the **Features** table. Even though they are unnecessary, they exist and can't be deleted.

The tricky part is that when the results from both tables are merged, any non-skipped records from the **Features** table need to be inserted into the results from the **Articles** table in the exact order they appears in the **Features** table.

So lets say I have 6 records in the **Features** table, A - F and the order field ranges from 1 - 6. Records A,B,D,E all have a value of 1 in the *Skip* field. That means I'm only interested in records C and F both of which need to be inserted into the final record set in positions 3 and 6 respectively.

The records may look something like this for the **Articles** table:

```
+----+------------+
| id |    date    | 
+----+------------+
| 1  | 9999999999 |
+----+------------+
| 2  | 9999999998 |
+----+------------+
| 3  | 9999999997 |
+----+------------+
| 4  | 9999999996 |
+----+------------+
| 5  | 9999999995 |
+----+------------+
| 6  | 9999999994 |
+----+------------+
| 7  | 9999999993 |
+----+------------+
| 8  | 9999999992 |
+----+------------+
| 9  | 9999999991 |
+----+------------+
| 10 | 9999999990 |
+----+------------+
```

The **Features** table may look something like this:

```
+----+------+-------+------+
| id | name | delta | skip |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 11 |   A  |   1   |   1  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 12 |   B  |   2   |   1  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 13 |   C  |   3   |   0  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 14 |   D  |   4   |   1  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 15 |   E  |   5   |   1  |
+----+------+-------+------+
| 16 |   F  |   6   |   0  |
+----+------+-------+------+
```

The results would look something like this (not including any additional fields that might be needed to achieve my goal):

```
+----+
| id |
+----+
| 1  |
+----+
| 2  |
+----+
| 13 | (record from the Features table in the third position)
+----+
| 3  |
+----+
| 4  |
+----+
| 16 | (record from the Features table in the sixth position)
+----+
| 5  |
+----+
| 6  |
+----+
| 7  |
+----+
| 8  |
+----+
| 9  |
+----+
| 10 |
+----+
```

Hope my explanation makes sense. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Howie

Comment: SQL tables are inherently unordered.  So, the order of inserting is irrelevant.  You need to think about a separate column that stores the ordering.

Comment: I was thinking about doing that and adding a flag to the Features table so they are always order before the records with the same Order value from the Articles table, but here's my problem. If the Articles table has an Order field with the numbers 1-10 and I tried to merge the two tables, I'd have two records where Order = 3 and Order = 6, one from Articles and one from Features. While the 3rd record in the final set might be the one from the Features table, the 6th would actually be 5th record from the Articles table. Article 1, 2, Feature 3, Article 3, 4, 5, Feature 6, Article 6...WTF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [this example in SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/edfdc/1) did it for me.

```
SELECT id, sort_order FROM (
SELECT `date`, NULL delta, id, (@a_count:=@a_count+1) sort_order
  FROM Articles a_main, (SELECT @a_count:=-1) z

  UNION ALL

SELECT a.`date`, f.delta, f.id, f.weighted_rn
  FROM (
    SELECT (@x:=@x+1) rn, a.*
    FROM Articles a, (SELECT @x:=-1) z
    ORDER BY a.`date` DESC
  ) a

JOIN (
    SELECT (@y:=@y+1) rn, TRUNCATE((f.delta - @y - (1/@y)),2) AS weighted_rn, f.id, f.delta, f.skip
    FROM Features f, (SELECT @y:=-1) z
    WHERE f.skip <> 1
    ORDER BY f.delta
  ) f

ON a.rn = f.rn
ORDER BY sort_order
) merge
```

Thanks to [Kordirko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2568341/kordirko) for the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that there is a mistake in your example - record id=16 is sixth row in Features table, so should be after id=5 in results, not before.


Try the blelow query. Here is [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/84f6e/20).

```
select id from (
  select `date`, null delta, id
  from Articles
  union all
  select a.`date`, f.delta, f.id 
  from ( 
    select (@x:=@x+1) rn, a.*
    from Articles a, (select @x:=0) z
    order by a.`date` desc
  ) a
  join (
    select (@y:=@y+1) rn, f.id, f.delta, f.skip
    from Features f, (select @y:=0) z
    order by f.delta
  ) f
  on a.rn = f.rn
  where f.skip <> 1
  order by `date` desc, isnull( delta ), delta 
) merge
```

Comment: You're right, that was my mistake. The solution is brilliant, however, it isn't accounting for the intended insertion position. While ID 13 does occur 3rd, ID 16 should occur 6th, but instead occurs 7th.